# How do i arranged and fill the missing fields from reading two files in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have two text files

cat A.txt

```
10,1,1,"ABC"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"S2"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,3,"ABC"
```

cat B.txt

```
10,1,1,"ABC1"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,4,"bokaj"
```

I want to find the missing fields by reading from two text files and fill up  in both the files for missing fields by "  " and save to two new modified files How do i get this say

A1.txt is a modified version of A.txt

cat A1.txt

```
10,1,1,"ABC"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"S2"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,3,"ABC"
10,2,4,"  "
```

B1.txt is a modified version of B.txt

cat B1.txt

```
10,1,1,"ABC1"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"  "
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,3,"  "
10,2,4,"bokaj"
```

make sure that total number of lines in A1.txt is same as that of B1.txt, i am new to bash, your answer with explaination may help me to learn this alot.

This is my MWE which i have tried so far

```
#!/bin/bash


cut -d ',' -f1,2,3 A.txt > A1.txt
cut -d ',' -f1,2,3 B.txt > B1.txt


## Command to print contents which are in B1.txt but not in A1.txt

A=`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' A1.txt B1.txt`
echo $A,'" "' >> A.txt
sort A.txt

## Command to print contents which are in A1.txt but not in B1.txt

B=`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' B1.txt A1.txt`
echo $B,'" "' >> B.txt
sort B.txt
```

Comment: elaborate more. What do you mean by missing field ?

Comment: do you mean missing field or missing row ?

Comment: This is going to be tricky because your files don't have a unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `diff` then `sort` can come in handy here.

For the `A.txt` and `B.txt` files with their respective companions `A1.txt` and `B1.txt` files already set up as in your example, do:

```
diff --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= --new-line-format='%l,"  "'%c\'\\12\' A1.txt B1.txt | sort -st , -k 1,3 A.txt -
```

and:

```
diff --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= --new-line-format='%l,"  "'%c\'\\12\' B1.txt A1.txt | sort -st , -k 1,3 B.txt -
```

These should yield the output you described.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -vFf B.txt A.txt | sed 's/".*"/" "/' |  sort -st, -k1,3 - B.txt
```

result (B1.txt):

```
10,1,1," "
10,1,1,"ABC1"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1," "
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,3," "
10,2,4,"bokaj"
```

The 1st line is different from you sample, but i think it should be there as `ABC` is different from `ABC1`.